# Presenting three alternatives

Tags: word-choice

How could I express the following sentence implying that only one option can be chosen?

> I don't know **( X )** Carla will go for juice, water or alcohol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To this US English speaker, the simplest and probably best way to phrase it is

> I don't know **whether** Carla will go for juice, water or alcohol.

because [*whether* is used to introduce two or more alternatives](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whether).  The normal implication here is that she will choose only one.  If you absolutely had to make it clear that one and only one has to be chosen, I guess you could say

> I don't know **which one of** juice, water or alcohol Carla will go for.

but that seems more awkward than the first choice.

Answer (score 1):

To express the idea that only one option out of possible multiple options can be chosen, we use the construction *either* ... *or*.

Example:

> If you win, you will **either** receive a computer, a house **or** a car. Only one of those, but not all three together.

But in your particular situation, you'd be probably better off using a simple *if* conjunction:

> I don't know **if** Carla will go for juice, water or alcohol.

It is also possible to use *whether* instead. Technically speaking, the only difference between the two is that the latter sounds a bit more formal. But that's rather a technical detail. Realistically, they can be used absolutely interchangeably.

Comment: Here either is not an adverb, it is a correlative conjunction used with or.

Comment: I don't know if Carla will go for juice, water or alcohol... or if she will decide not to.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the conjunction **if** or **whether** would make the sentence grammatically correct. The choice of the option has already been implied by another conjunction used by you - **or**.
However, it does not guarantee the person necessarily choosing only one drink. For that you could use the correlative conjunction **either**... or.

I don't know **if** Carla will go for juice, water or alcohol.

Carla could **either** choose juice, water **or** alcohol.